# Fast, good quality pixel interpolation for extreme image downscaling

Tags: c++, image-processing, visual-studio-2012, interpolation

In my program, I am downscaling an image of 500px or larger to an extreme level of approx 16px-32px. The source image is user-specified so I do not have control over its size. As you can imagine, few pixel interpolations hold up and inevitably the result is heavily aliased.

I've tried bilinear, bicubic and square average sampling. The square average sampling actually provides the most decent results but the smaller it gets, the larger the sampling radius has to be. As a result, it gets quite slow - slower than the other interpolation methods.

I have also tried an adaptive square average sampling so that the smaller it gets the greater the sampling radius, while the closer it is to its original size, the smaller the sampling radius. However, it produces problems and I am not convinced this is the best approach.

So the question is: What is the recommended type of pixel interpolation that is fast and works well on such extreme levels of downscaling?

I do not wish to use a library so I will need something that I can code by hand and isn't too complex. I am working in C++ with VS 2012.

Here's some example code I've tried as requested (hopefully without errors from my pseudo-code cut and paste). This performs a 7x7 average downscale and although it's a better result than bilinear or bicubic interpolation, it also takes quite a hit:

```
    // Sizing control
    ctl(0): "Resize",Range=(0,800),Val=100

    // Variables
    float fracx,fracy;
    int Xnew,Ynew,p,q,Calc;
    int x,y,p1,q1,i,j;

    //New image dimensions
    Xnew=image->width*ctl(0)/100;
    Ynew=image->height*ctl(0)/100;

    for (y=0; y<image->height; y++){ // rows
    for (x=0; x<image->width; x++){ // columns

        p1=(int)x*image->width/Xnew;
        q1=(int)y*image->height/Ynew;

        for (z=0; z<3; z++){ // channels

             for (i=-3;i<=3;i++) {
             for (j=-3;j<=3;j++) {
             Calc += (int)(src(p1-i,q1-j,z)); 
             } //j
             } //i

             Calc /= 49;

             pset(x, y, z, Calc);

         }  // channels         


    }  // columns
    }  // rows
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need to do averaging, algorithms that sample without averaging are not suitable for downscaling an image in general. Averaging over pixels in a square neighborhood is the cheapest solution, not ideal but OK in general. You do need to implement it carefully to avoid cache misses. Run through the input image in storage order, and accumulate pixel values in the right locations of the output image.

Comment: I don't understand how you plan to use bilinear or bicubic interpolation if you plan to sample. As Cris Luengo said, you just need one pass over the input image to obtain your output, so the complexity is linear in the number of pixels. Show us some code, so we can suggest possible improvements.

Comment: I've added sample code, as requested.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are doing this yourself? I would guess this is a solved problem in most of the many image-processing libraries out there?

Comment: The main reason is to learn what goes on behind the scenes and the second is because I've never managed to a library to work easily and for my needs. I would very much prefer to do it manually.

Comment: For an "accurate" reduction, if you have a 500x500 source image that you want to downscale to 25x25, you should be averaging 20x20 pixel tiles in the source image.  (This gets tricky if the source size is not a multiple of the dest since you need to factor in fractional pixels at the seams.)

Answer (score 1):

The first point is to use pointers to your data. Never use indexes at every pixel. When you write: `src(p1-i,q1-j,z)` or `pset(x, y, z, Calc)` how much computation is being made? Use pointers to data and manipulate those.

Second: your algorithm is wrong. You don't want an average filter, but you want to make a grid on your source image and for every grid cell compute the average and put it in the corresponding pixel of the output image.

The specific solution should be tailored to your data representation, but it could be something like this:

```
    std::vector<uint32_t> accum(Xnew);
    std::vector<uint32_t> count(Xnew);
    uint32_t *paccum, *pcount;
    uint8_t* pin = /*pointer to input data*/;
    uint8_t* pout = /*pointer to output data*/;
    for (int dr = 0, sr = 0, w = image->width, h = image->height; sr < h; ++dr) {
        memset(paccum = accum.data(), 0, Xnew*4);
        memset(pcount = count.data(), 0, Xnew*4);
        while (sr * Ynew / h == dr) {
            paccum = accum.data();
            pcount = count.data();
            for (int dc = 0, sc = 0; sc < w; ++sc) {
                *paccum += *i;
                *pcount += 1;
                ++pin;
                if (sc * Xnew / w > dc) {
                    ++dc;
                    ++paccum;
                    ++pcount;
                }
            }
            sr++;
        }
        std::transform(begin(accum), end(accum), begin(count), pout, std::divides<uint32_t>());
        pout += Xnew;
    }
```

This was written using my own library (still in development) and it seems to work, but later I changed the variables names in order to make it simpler here, so I don't guarantee anything!

The idea is to have a local buffer of 32 bit ints which can hold the partial sum of all pixels in the rows which fall in a row of the output image. Then you divide by the cell count and save the output to the final image.

The first thing you should do is to set up a performance evaluation system to measure how much any change impacts on the performance.

Answer (score 0):

As said precedently, you should not use indexes but pointers for (probably) a substantial
speed up & not simply average as a basic averaging of pixels is basically a blur filter.

I would highly advise you to rework your code to be using "kernels". This is the matrix representing the ratio of each pixel used. That way, you will be able to test different strategies and optimize quality.

Example of kernels:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)

Upsampling/downsampling kernel:
http://www.johncostella.com/magic/

Note, from the code it seems you apply a 3x3 kernel but initially done on a 7x7 kernel. The equivalent 3x3 kernel as posted would be:

```
[1 1 1]
[1 1 1] * 1/9
[1 1 1]
```